# Place symbols from small to big

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, sorting, printing

I am wondering how to compare the different values of `ω` I derived in this code, and place them in order as follows. (use `Print` or something?)

I would like to have `ω` placed in order in the output, instead of the values of `ω`.

> $$\omega_{11} < \omega_{22} < \omega_2 < \omega_1$$

I would like to have `ω` placed in order in the output, instead of the values of `ω`.

```
Remove["Global`*"]

x1[t_] = A1 E^(I ω t);
x2[t_] = A2 E^(I ω t);

eqn1 = m x1''[t] + 2 k x1[t] - k x2[t] == 0 /. t -> 0;
eqn2 = m x2''[t] - k x1[t] + k x2[t] == 0 /. t -> 0;

org = k/m SparseArray[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}} -> {2, -1, -1, 1}];

eigena = Sqrt[org // Eigenvalues];

"The charactersitic frequencies are: "
Column[Subscript[ω, #] & /@ Range@2 == eigena // Thread, 
 Spacings -> 2]
For[i = 1, i < 3, i++, Subscript[ω, i] = eigena[[i]]]

"When the upper mass m1 is fixed, x1[t]=0, for all t values"

eqn11 = x2''[t] == -k/m x2[t];

"Just by observation, the frequency is:"

Subscript[ω, 11] == Sqrt[k/m]
Subscript[ω, 11] = Sqrt[k/m];

"When the upper mass m2 is fixed, x2[t]=0, for all t values"

eqn22 = x1''[t] == -2 k/m x1[t];

"Just by observation, the frequency is:"

Subscript[ω, 22] == Sqrt[2 k/m]
Subscript[ω, 22] = Sqrt[2 k/m];


Sort[{Subscript[ω, 1], Subscript[ω, 2], Subscript[ω, 11], Subscript[ω, 22]}
        ] /. k -> 1 /. m -> 1
```

Comment: @Kuba Is the question clear after I revised it?

Comment: Yes it is but is the rest of the code relevant, isn't it only about the last line?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, it's about the last line. But I also feel that my code doesn't look nice, so I am wondering if someone may help me polish it.

Comment: @Kuba Do you know how to make `ω` appear among the `<`, instead of the numerical values?

Comment: @Kuba I know how to sort the numerical values in order, but how to make a connection to their symbols `ω`, and place them in order? This is my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ugly ;), but I think it is what you are after.

```
Composition[
  Row[#[[;; , 1]], " < "] &,
  SortBy[#, N[#[[2]]] &] &,
  ReleaseHold,
  MapAt[HoldForm, #, {1, ;; , 1}] &,
  # /. s_Subscript :> RuleCondition@{HoldForm[s], s /. k -> 1 /. m -> 1} &
  ]@Hold[{Subscript[ω, 1], Subscript[ω, 2], Subscript[ω, 11], Subscript[ω, 22]}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Indeed, it is quite complicated. Do you know is there other simpler command to accomplish this?

Comment: @Lawerance generally you can do something like: `{"a", "b", "c", "d"}[[Ordering[{1, 3, 2, 0}]]]` but I've assumed you want all that to do programmatically and you have not written those names as strings for example. That's why it is so long. Feel free to hold on with an accept, maybe someone will provide better answer.

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right. That's why I think my code does not look nice.

Answer (score 6):

I think this does what you want:

```
Less @@ SortBy[Defer[Subscript[ω, #]] & /@ {1, 2, 11, 22}, N @@ # &]
```

[image]

Comment: This is so clean. +1